# Switching letters in a string in C

Tags: c, string, switch-statement, swap, letters

I'm not sure why this code does not work.

This code is supposed to, for example, switch all a's in the string to b's, and all b's to a's and print the result.

input:

```
abcd
a b
c d
```

Intended output:

```
badc
```

Code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j;

    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

    char s[n+1], x[m+1], y[m+1];

    scanf("%s", s);

    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &x[i]);
        scanf("%c", &y[i]);
    }

    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(s[i] == x[j])
                s[i] = y[j];
            else if(s[i] == y[j])
                s[i] = x[j];
        }
    }

    printf("%s", s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are switching `c` with `d` and `d` with `c` too in your output.

Comment: This is just an example. The user is meant to switch whatever letter he enters to another letter and vice versa.

Comment: Can you print stuff out each iteration and see what's there?

Comment: @ergonaut sure. I tried it just now and apparently x[0] = nothing, but y[0] = a. Not sure why x[0] != a and y[0] != b.....

Comment: You need a space in this line `scanf("%c", &x[i]);` before the `%c` so it reads `scanf(" %c", &x[i]);` and the same witht the following line. This is to remove the white-space left in the input buffer after the previous `scanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay give me a moment I'll try that.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're a genius. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Finally we got another genius on SO. Let's celebrate! :) @WeatherVane

Comment: @haccks is there some sarcasm there? I only RTM.

Comment: @WeatherVane; Haha. No. Its not a sarcasm. Just for fun. Hope you will not mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented you need a space before the `%c` in these lines

```
scanf("%c", &x[i]);
scanf("%c", &y[i]);
```

to prevent the `%c` format type reading the white-space left in the input buffer by previous `scanf` calls. Change to

```
scanf(" %c", &x[i]);
scanf(" %c", &y[i]);
```

Comment: How do I reduce the time limit of this program?

Comment: What time limit? Is this a different question?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. You just need to put a space before `%c` specifier in both of the `scanf`

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    scanf(" %c", &x[i]);
    scanf(" %c", &y[i]);
}
```

and it will work. This is because the `\n` leftover by the previous `scanf` is read by second `scanf` and same is happening for the space in between the the input characters `a b` and `c d`. A space before `%c` in `scanf` will consume all white-spaces.

You can change loop to replace characters in only one iteration

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if(s[i] == x[j])
        {
            s[i] = y[j];
            break;
        }
        if(s[i] == y[j])
        {
            s[i] = x[j];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I reduce the time limit of this program?

Comment: @haccks is there an execution time penalty for the redundant `else`?

Comment: @WeatherVane; `else` is not redundant but more comparisons will take more time assuming `m` has some big value.

Comment: @haccks the `else` is redundant because of the preceding `break` when the previous condition was true.

Comment: @WeatherVane; Ummm....... if previous is not true then `else` part will execute. But, you are right. `else` is redundant, but there is no execution time penalty. Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397902/2410359

Code does not insure that `s` is null character terminated at print time - leads to undefined behavior.  Should use `for(i = 0; s[i] && i<n; i++)` to prevent overwriting it.

This may account for excessive time usage.

---

OP posts below as input.  Certainly 2 numbers must precede that for `scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);`

```
abcd
a b
c d
```